# Do we need to permit ruby virtual attributes also?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jcrop, strong-parameters

Till now I thought, I have to permit only those attributes which I required to save in database. But recently I used Jcrop to crop my User avatar and it has 4 virtual attributes which will be sent after crop from the front end,

Here is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

  after_update :crop_avatar

  def crop_avatar
    avatar.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?
  end
end
```

When I submit after crop, my console log says

```
unpermitted params: crop_x, crop_y, crop_h, crop_w
```

and the image is not cropped.

But if I permit these virtual attributes as

```
params.require(:user).permit(:avatar,:crop_x,:crop_y,:crop_h,:crop_w)
```

then image were cropped successfully.

So the question is why do I need to permit these virtual attributes, even if this is not saved in database?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters):

> With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to
>   be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been
>   whitelisted.

So there is no discrimination between normal and virtual attributes here, it is just about allowing parameters for mass assignment. What your model does with those parameters is up to you.