# Carrierwave and Jcrop and Devise, Jcrop is not cropping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, carrierwave, jcrop

Carrierwave and Jcrop and Devise, Jcrop is not cropping

I am using Devise for authentication and Carrierwave + Jcrop (gem 'jcrop-rails-v2 ') for users to crop their avatar. I'm following the this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised) , after completing the railscasts, for some reason, It's not cropping. I'm not sure if it has something to do with `Devise` or `Jcrop`

Please see below my codes and screenshots I took. As you can see in the screenshots, After clicking "crop", the image should be the same as the 'preview' but instead it becomes only smaller version of the actuall image. 
[image]
[image]

### crop.html.erb

```
<h1>Crop Avatar</h1>

<%= image_tag @user.image_url(:large), id: "cropbox" %>

<h4>Preview</h4>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
  <%= image_tag @user.image.url(:large), :id => "preview" %>
</div>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}" %>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Crop" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  new ImageCropper()

class ImageCropper
  constructor: ->
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop
      aspectRatio: 1
      setSelect: [0, 0, 600, 600]
      onSelect: @update
      onChange: @update

  update: (coords) =>
    $('#user_crop_x').val(coords.x)
    $('#user_crop_y').val(coords.y)
    $('#user_crop_w').val(coords.w)
    $('#user_crop_h').val(coords.h)
    @updatePreview(coords)

  updatePreview: (coords) =>
          $('#preview').css
                  width: Math.round(100/coords.w * $('#cropbox').width()) + 'px'
                  height: Math.round(100/coords.h * $('#cropbox').height()) + 'px'
                  marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.w * coords.x) + 'px'
                  marginTop: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.h * coords.y) + 'px'
```

### registrations_controller.erb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def update
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

        successfully_updated = if account_update_params[:password].blank?
           params[:user].delete(:current_password)
           @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
         else
           @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
         end

         if successfully_updated
            set_flash_message :notice, :updated
            sign_in @user, :bypass => true
            if params[:user][:image].present?
              render "crop"
            else
              redirect_to "/users/3"
            end
         else
            render "edit"
         end
  end


protected



end
```

### image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

version :large do
    resize_to_limit(600, 600)
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(100, 100)
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(600, 600)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
      end
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: can you also attach the uploader also not sure if you know this what params are sanitize on `[account_update]` (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/b786c384d54a6365bdc6c0cf6068dc5325a301a9/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L90) I'm surprize how come your images is getting saved

Comment: ok , please check the updated question. This is my [account_update]`devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :image )}`

Comment: ok cool but where are you permitting `crop_x`,`crop_y`,`crop_h`,`crop_w` also attach your params as well

Comment: in my user model (user.rb), I wrote `attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h`, it's kind of weird cos I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: that right but since you are mass assign since I dont see anywhere you explicitly assign `crox_[x|y|h|w]` you have to sanitize those from params as well hence I asked you to attach your `params` in the question

Comment: Check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034872/do-i-need-to-permit-my-virtual-attributes-also`

Comment: thanks for the link,since Im using Devise, and have overwrite the `Registration Controller` to handle `User` Updates, so I can't put something like `params.require(:user).permit(:image,:crop_x,:crop_y,:crop_h,:crop_w)`inside my `User controller` cos that's not how Devise handles Strong Parameters. If I replace `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :image )}` with `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u|
      u.permit(:username, :image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h )}` it gives me `undefined local variable or method 'crop_x' for #<User>`

Comment: Can you paster your params pleasse

Comment: sorry, don't know what you mean.

Comment: I need the snapshot of the parameters that is been passed to server

Answer (score 0):

```
def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w..
```

I did that and it works!